# Question about matrix multiplication notation

Tags: matrices

I have the following matrices:

$A=\begin{pmatrix}
        -\frac{2}{3} & \frac{1}{3} & 0 \\
        \frac{1}{6} & -\frac{1}{3} & \frac{1}{2} \\
        \frac{1}{6} & \frac{1}{3} & \frac{1}{2} \\
        \end{pmatrix}$
; $B=\begin{pmatrix}
        2 & 3\\
        2 & 0 \\
        0 & 3\\
        \end{pmatrix}$
; $C=\begin{pmatrix}
        6 & 3& 4 \\
        6 & 6 & 0 \\
        \end{pmatrix}$
;$u=\begin{pmatrix}2 \\ -5 \\ 4 \end{pmatrix}$

I want to calculate the following:

$\sum_j a_{ij}u_j$

$\sum_{jk} c_{ij}a_{jk}b_{kl}$

but I am not used to this kind of notation. Does the first one mean to multiply all $i$-rows of A with the $j$-column of u?

$\implies AB=\begin{pmatrix}
        -\frac{2}{3} & \frac{1}{3} & 0 \\
        \frac{1}{6} & -\frac{1}{3} & \frac{1}{2} \\
        \frac{1}{6} & \frac{1}{3} & \frac{1}{2} \\
        \end{pmatrix} \cdot \begin{pmatrix}2 \\ -5 \\ 4 \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}-3 \\ 4 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}$?

I am not sure what the second one is trying to say? Maybe $C\cdot A\cdot B$?

Comment: Yes, the second is $CAB$. $C$ is 2x3 matrix, $A$ is 3x3 amd $B$ is 3x2. $CAB$ is possible and is expected to be 2x2. Maybe you are confused with the $\sum_{jk}$. It is just a short hand notation for a double notation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$a_{ij}$ denotes the $i^{th}$ row and $j^{th}$ column of $A$. The first summation means keeping $i$ fixed, increment the $j$ parameter as below for each $i$.
$$\sum_j a_{ij}u_j = a_{i1}u_1+a_{i2}u_2+a_{i3}u_3$$

This translates to the product $A.U$.

Similarly for the second sum.

Comment: Thanks. I am still confused about the index $i$. How do I know that this sum is telling me to multiply all rows in $A$ with the $j^{th}$-column in $B$. Why not just the first row?

Comment: It isn't explicitly telling you to multiply all rows, but since no $i$ is specified and one can see that the product is similar to matrix multiplication, we can safely assume that we have to find the product over all $i$s, that is, multiply the two matrices.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Note that you can perform the usual rows-columns product of two matrices $AB$ only if the number of  columns of $A$ is the same as the number of rows of $B$.